# Web api with two gets that do different actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I have two get statements in a controller

```
        [HttpGet("{projectId:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Models.Project>> GetById(int projectId)
    {
        var project = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(projectId);

        if (project == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return project;

    }

    // GET: api/project/5
    [HttpGet("{projectCode}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Project>> GetProjectByProjectCode(string projectCode)
    {
        var projects = await _context.Projects.FindAsync(projectCode);


        if (projects == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       
        return projects; 
    }
```

The first get works perfectly and does what it is supposed to do pass in an ID and return the project associated with that ID

The second get does not work like it is supposed to.  What it is supposed to do is pass in a projectCode parameter (string) and return the project associated with that project code.

The project codes are formatted like this --7000316139.13.01-- so that is why I am passing it using a string parameter

When I run the api with swagger I get the following error

> > System.ArgumentException: The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet.Find' was of type 'string', which does not match the
> > property type of 'int'.    at
> > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.FindTracked(Object[] keyValues, IReadOnlyList`1& keyProperties)    at
> > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.EntityFinder`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[]
> > keyValues)    at
> > Mcr.PRT.PM.Service.Controllers.ProjectController.GetProjectByProjectCode(String
> > projectCode) in
> > C:\Users\MaxGay\Source\Repos\PRT2\ProjectManagementService\Controllers\ProjectController.cs:line
> > 98    at lambda_method(Closure , Object )    at
> > Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> > at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> > mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> > arguments)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> > invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> > invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> > isCompleted)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> > context)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> > next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> > --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> > invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> > isCompleted)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> > context)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> > next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> > --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> > invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> > endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > httpContext)    at
> > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > context)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > context)    at
> > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > httpContext)    at
> > Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> > context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: text/plain Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 Host: localhost Referer:
> https://localhost/index.html User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83
> Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.41 :method: GET :authority: localhost
> :scheme: https :path: /api/Project/7000316139.13.01 sec-fetch-site:
> same-origin sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-dest: empty

I am not sure what the error is and why it is happening?

I have tried to switch the GetProjectsByProjectCode to public IActionResult but that did not help either

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question accordingly. In particular either remove all DB related code (if problem is about routing in WebAPI and passing paramters to actions, which based on stack trace is unlikely the case) or update code and text in the question to just ask about why passing string to method that expects int is not working.

Comment: The error seems pretty straight forward, your primary key is an int but you're trying to find by string...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes that is what I determined as well.  Lack of sleep and frustration I believe attributed to this post

Answer (score 0):

As ChiefTwoPencils pointed out the issue here is the primary key is an int and I am passing a string.  I think I should probably get some sleep